# Structuring spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Is it possible to perform a different set of transformations parallel on a single DStream source?

For example: 
I might read a file and get a single DStream. Is it possible to perform
     1. reduceByKey and other operations
     2. reduceByKeyAndWindow and many more
     3. Some other aggregate and more

The above 3 set of operations are independent and must be performed separately from a single source.
The question is, what are the effects of reshuffle?
Assume, all 3 dont require reshuffling and they are evaluated in parallel as opposed to one of the steps requires reshuffle. That will result in two different results?

Trying to understand the flow of a spark job. Is it possible to run multiple different transformations parallel that would require reshuffle?
In such case, it is better to run multiple spark jobs altogether?